# The storage construction of user avatar

Tags: php, apache, photo, user-profile, avatar

User avatar is an important part of every website. How should I store the avatar image files on the server with high performance?

Here are some points have to solve:

1. How to generate the file name of user? Directly by user id or name,
   or by the hashed/md5 id/name?
2. How to storage the file? All in one dictionary or in different dictionary (How to?).
3. The avatar file can cacheable if the link of the file is permalink, but what if the user change the new avatar?

Comment: Define what you mean by "high performance"  Best performance on upload? Best performance with regard to the database? Best performance with regard to user download speed?  Best performance with regards to minimizing server impact to serving image files? Best performance with regard to file caching? Best performance with regard to file storage requirements? Best performance based on how much you are willing to spend on infrastructure costs?

Comment: possibly duplicate or at least similar of this sad soul: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11888877/should-user-avatars-be-saved-in-a-private-directory

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I store a text field in the user's database row, of the format:

```
WWW|HHH|URL
```

The width and height (`WWW` and `HHH`) are fetched when the user selects the file, and the URL is simply the address where the avatar can be found.

You actually save a huge amount of bandwidth by not putting user's avatars on your servers.

Comment: +1 for answering a question I've tried to get answered for almost a month now. haha